# How can I do an interpolating reindex in pandas using datetime indices?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, reindex

I have a series with a datetime index, and what I'd like is to interpolate this data using some other, arbitrary datetime index.  Essentially what I want is how to make the following code snippet more or less work:

```
from pandas import Series
import datetime

datetime_index = [datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 5), datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 10)]
data_series = Series([5, 15], [datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 5), datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 15)])

def interpolating_reindex(data_series, datetime_index):
    """?????"""

goal_series = interpolating_reindex(data_series, datetime_index) 

assert(goal_series == Series([5, 10], datetime_index))
```

`reindex` doesn't do what I want because it can't interpolate, and also my series might not have the same indices anyway.  `resample` isn't what I want because I want to use an arbitrary, already defined index which isn't necessarily periodic.  I've also tried combining indices using `Index.join` in the hopes that I could then do `reindex` and then `interpolate`, but that didn't work as I expected.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pandas import Series
import datetime

datetime_index = [datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 5), datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 10)]
s1 = Series([5, 15], [datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 5), datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 15)])
s2 = Series(None, datetime_index)
s3 = s1.combine_first(s2)
s3.interpolate()
```

Based on the comments, the result interpolated to the target index would be:

```
goal_series  = s3.interpolate().reindex(datetime_index)

assert((goal_series == Series([5, 10], datetime_index)).all())
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me most of the way there.  After `interpolate` I could then use `reindex` to get back down to just the desired index.