# Python pandas time series interpolation and regularization

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, regularized

I am using Python Pandas for the first time. I have 5-min lag traffic data in csv format:

```
...
2015-01-04 08:29:05,271238
2015-01-04 08:34:05,329285
2015-01-04 08:39:05,-1
2015-01-04 08:44:05,260260
2015-01-04 08:49:05,263711
...
```

There are several issues:

- for some timestamps there's missing data (-1)
- missing entries (also 2/3 consecutive hours)
- the frequency of the observations is not exactly 5 minutes, but actually loses some seconds once in a while

I would like to obtain a regular time series, so with entries every (exactly) 5 minutes (and no missing valus). I have successfully interpolated the time series with the following code to approximate the -1 values with this code:

```
ts = pd.TimeSeries(values, index=timestamps)
ts.interpolate(method='cubic', downcast='infer')
```

How can I both interpolate and regularize the frequency of the observations? Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change the `-1`s to NaNs:

```
ts[ts==-1] = np.nan
```

Then resample the data to have a 5 minute frequency.

```
ts = ts.resample('5T')
```

Note that, by default, if two measurements fall within the same 5 minute period, `resample` averages the values together.

Finally, you could linearly interpolate the time series according to the time:

```
ts = ts.interpolate(method='time')
```

---

Since it looks like your data already has roughly a 5-minute frequency, you
might need to resample at a shorter frequency so cubic or spline interpolation
can smooth out the curve:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [271238, 329285, -1, 260260, 263711]
timestamps = pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-04 08:29:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:34:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:39:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:44:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:49:05'])

ts = pd.Series(values, index=timestamps)
ts[ts==-1] = np.nan
ts = ts.resample('T').mean()

ts.interpolate(method='spline', order=3).plot()
ts.interpolate(method='time').plot()
lines, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = ['spline', 'time']
plt.legend(lines, labels, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly! There's a way I can instead first add the regular 5 minutes timestamps to the series with nan as values, and then interpolate them with an order 3 spline?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "add the regular 5 minutes timestamps to the series with nan as values", but I've added an example showing interpolation by `time` and with order-3 splines.

Comment: I mean, there would be any difference if instead linearly interpolate the time series with **resample()**, we build first a time series with the plain entries in the data, then we add entries of the type 

2015-01-01-08:00, nan
2015-01-01-08:05, nan

and so on, and finally interpolate them with an order 3 spline?

Comment: The resampling is done *before* and independent of the interpolation. You don't have to interpolate linearly. Just remove the line `ts.interpolate(method='time').plot()` and the associated `time` from `labels`. Then the above code interpolates the data with an order-3 spline alone.

Comment: this answer is super helpful, more than I can express with a +1

Comment: For my monthly data, I had use "ts = pd.Series(values, index=timestamps, dtype=float)" for it to work.

Comment: OK, so the 'T' in `ts.resample(rule='T',...)` comes from the aliases in  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases.  The `how='mean'` speaks to the new Series datetime index is calculated from the source data's time index.  And the actual interpolation of the data at the times is done in the `.interpolate(...)` that is passed to the `.plot()` method and then thrown away.  -- I find this procedure darn had to discover from the docs.  I guess the general method is to induce NANs by the resampling the time index, and then fill in the NANs with the interpolate()?

Comment: @DaveX: Yes! You've got it.

Comment: `how='mean'` tells `resample` how to *aggregate* values if multiple rows fall within the same period (in this case `T` indicates that the period frequency is 1 minute long.)

Comment: `Series.resample` also does missing-value fill-ins for upsampling with `fill_method={'pad'|'fill'|'bfill'}` but that parameter won't take the interpolation methods, and would interfere with a later interpolation since the np.nans are filled in.

Comment: Is there a way to interpolate a time series onto a different, arbitrary set of potentially irregular times with this?

Comment: @DaveX: Certainly. Instead of `resample`-ing the Series, use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to add new rows with `NaN` values. Then calling `Series.interpolate(method='time')` will fill in the missing values with interpolated values.

Comment: Or you could use `combine_first` as [HYRY shows here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772571/190597). (As I think about it,`combine_first` may be the better solution since you wouldn't have to union the old index with a new index as you would if you use `reindex`...)